# Fast and elegant way to build a hash store with two long keys

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

I need to combine two int values as a key and store an object associated to that to a hash store.

One way I consider doing this is:

```
unsigned long nodeId = 1;
unsigned long suffixId = 20;
unsigned long long uniqueEdgeKey = (unsigned long long) nodeId << 32;
uniqueEdgeKey |= suffixId;
```

But is there a better C++ / C++11 way doing this?

Also, what would you suggest using from performance perspective as hash store for this key and it's associated object instance as value?

Edit: Forgot to mention that for a given reason, I unfortunately can't use Boost. It needs to be done with std only.

Comment: `std::unordered_map`/`std::unordered_set` with `boost::hash_combine`.

Comment: Answer: do what boost does. Maintain that yourself then.

Comment: Copy the code. Test it. As mentioned, maintain it. GLHF.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. Could you also give a reason for why the key combination from my key combination code example would be bad, or ineffective?

Comment: As long as your node ID and suffix ID values are guaranteed to be between 0 and (2^32)-1 (inclusive), then OR-ing them together like that will work fine.